# Temperatures dependence of aromaticity

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Does aromaticity depend on temperature?  I recently read about a compound (tropone) which changes its aromatic nature with temperature. Is it plausible? If yes then why
does it happen?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking if the (impossible) compound in the photo you provided meets that criteria? As of right now I'm not really sure what kind of explanation you want.

Comment: @ringo Maybe I'm running in low-brain mode due to a cold, but the compound looks like tropone to me. The corresponding resonance structure would be a tropylium oxide. The latter is aromatic.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha I didn't see that it was a seven membered ring... Maybe I'm the one running in low-brain mode after all...

Comment: @ringo No worries,  I counted more than once. Go figure :D

Comment: This compound is non aromatic at room temperature but at higher temperature it is aromatic.

Comment: Also called tropone and is aromatic. The energy needed to disrupt the electronic energy involved in aromaticity will be huge, the molecule would probably decompose in trying to do so.